Conditional Expectation in Diffusion Process
Consider a $d$-dimensional diffusion process $\mathbf{X}=(\mathbf{X}_t)_{t\in [0,T]}=([X^1_t,...,X^d_t])_{t\in [0,T]}$ that is the unique strong solution of the following SDE:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 d X^1_t = \lambda_1(\mathbf{X}_t)dt + d W^1_t\\
 d X^2_t = \lambda_2(\mathbf{X}_t)dt + dW^2_t\\
 \cdots \\
 d X^d_t = \lambda_d(\mathbf{X}_t)dt + dW^d_t
\end{matrix}\right.$$
where $W^1, W^2, ..., W^d$ are independent Wiener processes.
Denote $\mathcal{F}_t^i:=\sigma(X_s^i; s\leq t)$ and $\mathcal{F}_t^C:=\sigma(\mathcal{F}_t^i; i\in C)$ as the filtration generated by $X^i_t$ and $\mathbf{X}^C_t$, respectively. The question is then: How to estimate the conditional expectations:
$$t\mapsto \mathbb{E}[X_t^i|\mathcal{F}_t^C], \quad t\mapsto \mathbb{E}[\lambda_i(\mathbf{X}_t)|\mathcal{F}_t^C]$$
for any $i=1,2,...,d$ and $C\subseteq [d]:=\{1,2,...,d\}$.

What kind of estimate do you want? We can freeze the Brownian motions that are being conditioned on to obtain something.

What I want to estimate is the function $t\mapsto \mathbb{E}[X_t^i|\mathcal{F}_t^C]$ (like the objective in optimal filtering). What do you mean by "freeze the Brownian motions that are being conditioned on"?

I’ve added the (tiny amount of) progress i’ve been able to make. Nice problem!

Are you okay with $\lambda$ being, say $C^2$, so that we can apply Ito’s? We can get something more then.

I notice that you conditioned on $\sigma(X^i)$, instead of $\sigma(W^i)$, rendering my approach invalid…

Indeed, I am conditioning on $\sigma(X^i)$. However, I would be interested to hear your thoughts on conditioning on $\sigma(W^i)$.

Ah great, i have undeleted my answer then.

Here’s my attempt at getting started. The following answer concerns the easier case of conditioning on $\sigma(\{W^i\}_{i \in C})$.
Without loss of generality, take $C = \{1, \dots k\}$.
Now for $1 \leq i \leq k$, conditional on $\mathcal F_t^C$, $X^i$ follows the dynamics
$$X^i_t= X^i_0 + \int_0^t \lambda_i (\mathbf X_s) \, ds + w_t,$$
where now $W^i = w^i \in C[0, t]$ is deterministic given $\mathcal F^C_t$.
As such, by taking conditional expectations, we have the equation
$$\mathbb E[X^i_t| \mathcal F^C_t] = X^i_0 + \int_0^t\mathbb E[\lambda_i (\mathbf X_s) | \mathcal F^C_s] \, ds+ w^i_t.$$
We can of course write similarly, for $i > k$,
$$\mathbb E[X^i_t| \mathcal F^C_t] = X^i_0 + \int_0^t\mathbb E[\lambda_i (\mathbf X_s) | \mathcal F^C_s] \, ds + W^i_t,$$
or in SDE form,
$$d \mathbb E[X^i_t| \mathcal F^C_t] = \mathbb E[\lambda_i (\mathbf X_t) | \mathcal F^C_t] \, dt + dW^i_t.$$
I am not sure how to proceed from here. We may be able to get something much more if $\lambda$ is assumed smooth enough to apply Ito’s formula.
